# group by day based on a particular column with its unique entries - ROR

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have two tables `ImportedContactUser` and `ImportedContact` and the former  contains a column `imported_contact_id`.

Now, there are many entries for the same `imported_contact_id` in the first table. What i want to do is to group the unique `imported_contact_id` entries by day.

I am able to group the unique entries by day but the challenge comes when  some entries which was imported yesterday are being imported today also by some other user, in that case same entries are being counted for yesterday and today when i group it by day.
So, what I'm trying to do is

1. first get the unique entries till date
2. then apply group by day on it

So that I will have only unique entries count on grouping by each day. But with this also I'm not having any luck.

Below are the images of my two tables:

[First image is for 'ImportedContactUser' table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWYHv.png)

[Second one is for 'ImportedContact' table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USCIc.png)

Current code for retrieving the data:

```
ImportedContactUser.where("platform_id = 6 and updated_at > ? and updated_at <= ?", DateTime.new(2016, 6, 1), Date.today.at_end_of_day).select("DISTINCT imported_contact_id").group("date_format(updated_at, '%Y-%m-%d')").count
```

Comment: Share sample data and output.

Comment: Add it to the question. Besides, share table structure and data. These help others to understand.